# Need help calling methods

Tags: python, class, methods

Hey I'm really new to Python and programming in general. I'm working on a project for school where I have to make an NPC say a random line of code from what I give to him to say. My professor gave us some lines of code to work with and we have to fill in a few lines ourselves. However, I'm having a hard time just getting the program to display any text at all on windows powershell. I've looked at many tutorials on this website, and, according to them, I'm doing everything correctly. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and why it is wrong?

```
from random import randint
class NPC (object):
    def __init__(self,name, phrases):
        self.__name = name
        self.__phrases = #Your code here

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.__description

    def add_phrase(self, phrase):
        #your one line of code here to add a phrase to the phrases an NPC can say

    def getPhrases(self):
        return self.__phrases

    def speak(self):
        #Your code here, no more than 2 lines to select a phrase at random and
        #return it

    def __str__(self):
        return "Good day, I am " + self.__name
```

Is what we are given as a template.

What I have so far is

```
from random import randint
class NPC (object):
def __init__(self,name, phrases):
    self.__name = name
    self.__phrases = ['Today is Tuesday', 'Today is Wednesday', 'Today is Thursday', 'Today is Friday']

def getDescription(self):
    return self.__description

def add_phrase(self, phrase):
    return "Howdy"

def getPhrases(self):
    return self.__phrases

def speak(self):
    for i in self.__phrases:
        return randint

def __str__(self):
    return "Good day, I am " + self.__name

c = NPC()
c.speak()
```

In addition, what should I put under the speak function so that it returns one of those phrases at random?

Comment: your professor gave you variables with __ at the start of their names?

Comment: I'm not sure whether StackOverflow should be used to solve homeworks. But of course to learn and understand the problem is good. You said nothing is displayed. The then question is what would make things appear? Just returning a value doesn't usually display anything (ignoring things like Jupyter). The `print` statement does.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. It's basically asking us to do your assignment. I'm looking for evidence that you understand the assignment and that you understand basic Python syntax, and I'm not seeing it. So I don't feel confident that a Stack Overflow answer would be understood either. What I would do in your place would be to go through basic Python tutorials. They're a dime a dozen on the web. That's where you should start. I'm afraid there are no shortcuts here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, take a look at the changes I did:

```
from random import randint

class NPC (object):

    def __init__(self,name, phrases):
        self.__name = name
        self.__phrases = phrases

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.__description

    def add_phrase(self, phrase):
        return "Howdy"

    def getPhrases(self):
        return self.__phrases

    def speak(self):
        rand = randint(0,len(self.__phrases)) #Selecting a random phrase
        print(self.__phrases[rand])


    def __str__(self):
        return "Good day, I am " + self.__name


name = "Stranger"
# Initializing phrase list and then passing it as an argument to the constructor.
phrases = ['Today is Tuesday', 'Today is Wednesday', 'Today is Thursday', 'Today is Friday']

c = NPC(name, phrases)
c.speak()
```

One of the outputs is:

```
Today is Wednesday
```

Comment: I like what you did, and it works, but is there a way to get the phrases under the constructor instead of outside and have it work the same way?

Comment: Taking for granted the code that you were given in the first place you can do something like this in your constructor: `phrases = ['Today is Tuesday', 'Today is Wednesday', 'Today is Thursday', 'Today is Friday']` and then `self.__phrases = phrases`. But I don't see any reason for doing so since your class will lose its flexibility.